# Find the height of a right prism with base-rhombus.

Tags: solid-geometry

The base of a right prism is a rhombus. Find the height of the prism, if its diagonals are d1 and d2.

Comment: And the side of the rhombus is a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint.

Let $h$ be an altitude of the prism.

Thus,
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{d_1^2-h^2}}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{d_2^2-h^2}}{2}\right)^2=a^2.$$